# Execution failed for task ':location:parseDebugLocalResources'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, geolocation, geolocator

i'm trying to run my project , i have this page where i want to get current location of the user
but i get a message error when i run it

Message error
** Execution failed for task ':location:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':location:androidApis'.

> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

```
  > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform:
```

C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.
> C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar **

The code in the page

```
// ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';


import '../rounded_button.dart';

class DemandeList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemandeList createState() => _DemandeList(); 
}
class _DemandeList extends State<DemandeList>{
  late bool _serviceEnabled;
  late PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
  LocationData? _userLocation;

  Future<void> _getUserLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();

    // Check if location service is enable
    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    // Check if permission is granted
    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    final _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    setState(() {
      _userLocation = _locationData;
    });
  }

  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
        String? Key ; 

        
   @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  
        
     

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Listes des demandes"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
          
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        
        stream: db.collection('ambulance')
        .where("etat", isEqualTo: "en cours")
        .snapshots(),
        
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          
  
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
              
                int lng;
                int lat;
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                  trailing: Text("Accepter",
                           style: TextStyle(
                             color: Colors.green,fontSize: 15
                             ),
                             ),
                  title: new Text(doc['id']) ,
                  subtitle: new Text(doc['etat']),
                   
                  
                   
                  onTap: () => {
                   _getUserLocation,
                   lat =  _userLocation?.latitude as int , 
                   lng = _userLocation?.longitude as int , 
                   db.collection("position").add({'lat': lat , "lng": lng ,}),
                   db.collection("ambulance").doc(doc.id).update({"etat": 'Accept'  }), 
                 
                  
                  }
                  
              
                  ),
                  
                   
                );
              }).toList(),
            
              
            );
        },
        
      ),
    );
  }
   
}
```